# Не удаётся добавить textview програмно

Tags: java, android

Имеется шаблон такого типа:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ololo">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="Текст"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Пытаюсь добавить очередной textview, но сделать это программно. Делаю это так:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
                            TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            txt.setText("123123123");
                            LinearLayout  newLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                            newLayout.addView(txt,0);
                        }
```

Код компилируется, но при эмуляции textview не добавляется. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: вы добавляете `txt` в `newLayout`, который никуда в итоге не добавляете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно ваши ошибка в этом методе

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
                            TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                            txt.setText("123123123");
                            LinearLayout  newLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                            newLayout.addView(txt,0);
                        }
```

Сначала вы инфлейтите `LinearLayout` с разметки:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
```

После чего создаете `TexView`

```
TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

А затем вы создаете непонятный `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout  newLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
```

и кладете в него `TexView`

```
newLayout.addView(txt,0);
```

В таком случае если после этого вы нигде не добавляете `newLayout` в свою разметку -  то получается что  вы просто добавляете свое TextView - вникуда.

Попробуйте ззаменить код на этот, может поможет:

```
@Override
public void run() {
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
   TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
   txt.setText("123123123");
   layout.addView(txt,0);
}
```

**UPD:**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ololo);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.weight = 0.01f;
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Custom text");
        linearLayout.addView(textView,params);
    }
}
```

Вот в таком виде, используя вашу разметку добавляеться новое `TextView', как сделать так что бы оно отображалась нормально надо подумать, я бы менял верстку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не помогло к сожалению

Comment: Я добавил код, так добавляеться, но с версткой надо шото думать!